# Pivot_longer on a file that updates daily

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Trying to pivot a data frame of Covid-19 deaths imported each day from the web (Johns Hopkins data). The current file is 414 columns wide, growing by one column per day. Pivot_longer works when I specify the width by column index but triggers an error when I try `last_col()`.

For example, this works:

```
CountyDeathsC <- CountyDeathsB %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(4:414), names_to="Date", values_to="Cumulative Deaths") %>% 
  group_by(FIPS, Population, Combined_Key) %>% 
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(DeathsToday = `Cumulative Deaths` - dplyr::lag(`Cumulative Deaths`, 
                                                      n = 1, default = 0),
       Deaths7DayAvg = round(zoo::rollapplyr(DeathsToday, 7, mean, na.rm=TRUE, fill=NA))) %>% 
  mutate(CumDeathsPer100k = `Cumulative Deaths` / (Population / 100000))
```

This code (excerpt) does not:

```
pivot_longer(cols = c(4:last_col()), names_to="Date", values_to="Cumulative Deaths")
```

I get an error saying the term "last_col()" is not recognized. So it looks like I have to go in each day and manually insert the index for the last column. Or is there a better answer?

Comment: Could you add the data using dput or code for reading it in some way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If you want to go from column 4 to the last column, probably just use ...`c(4:ncol(.)`...

Comment: Or (4: length(colnames (CountyDeathsC))

Comment: Or (cols = !any_of(1:3))

Comment: @CALUMPolwart `cols != 1:3` will try to evaluate and throw an error. The syntax would be `cols = -(1:3)` or `cols = !(1:3)`.

Comment: The solution suggested by deschen works. Thanks very much!